# How can I programmatically write and read random video watermarks?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I spent a few minutes trying to think of a clearer way to word my title, but I couldn't manage it, sorry.

I want to essentially [canary trap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canary_trap) video files: I am (hypothetically, this is not real but a personal exercise) offering them up to 5,000 different people, and if one gets leaked, I want to know who leaked it. Metadata is too easily emoved, so what I'd like to do is add a random and subtle watermark to each file, and store information about that in a database.

For example: on Joe Smith's copy, a 10x10 pixel 80% transparent red square in the upper left corner for 5 frames. On Diane Brown's copy, a full-width 5-pixel 90% transparent black bar on the bottom edge for 15 frames. Then, if I find a leaked copy, I could check it against the database.

I know this still isn't foolproof: cropping would break co-ordinates, hue/brightness transforms would break colour reading, cutting time would break timestamps. But if I did want to do this anyway, what would be a good strategy for it?

My idea was to generate PNG overlays randomly, split the video into parts with mkvtoolnix/ffmpeg, re-encode the middle part with ffmpeg + overlay filter, and then rejoin them. But is this silly when there's a "proper" way to do it? And what would I be doing to *read* the watermarks, which I can't even really conceive of?